# Spin the bottle application

Tags: swift, rotation

I have a app that spin a bottle.
When someone click a button, the bottle will spin.

Like the code is now, the bottle will spin 10 times, and then STOP at a random degree between 0 and 360. But i want the bottle to spin smootly and stop smootly, and not just STOP constant. I want the bottle to spin slower and slower.

Code:

```
func rotateRandom(){
    let diceRoll = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(360))
    let degree =  0.0174532925 as CGFloat
    let rotate = diceRoll
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear,      animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, rotate)
        }, completion: nil)
    //println(diceRoll)
}

func rotateLeft(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear,      animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, -180 * 0.0174532925)
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, -180 * 0.0174532925)
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, -180 * 0.0174532925)
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, -180 * 0.0174532925)
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, -180 * 0.0174532925)
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, -180 * 0.0174532925)
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, -180 * 0.0174532925)
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, -180 * 0.0174532925)
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, -180 * 0.0174532925)
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, -180 * 0.0174532925)
        //self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(360)
        }, completion: nil)
    rotateRandom()
}
```

Any suggestions here? I also want a function for when the bottle has stopped. So i can add a popup when the bottle has stopped.

Comment: Calling CGAffineTransformRotate like that over and over is not the night way to accomplish that. You are going to want to look into "easing" to assist in having it slow down at the end.

Comment: Angular velocity + angular deceleration will give you the angle at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the transform value a property and then have a timer increment the transform value and apply the transform to the single image. When it is time to slow down make the increment smaller and smaller until it was time to stop it.

Use `arc4ran_uniform()` for the random stop time.

Comment: How would i do that? I don´t really understand.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://markmanx.com/?p=33

As JoshStrange mentioned above, you'll want to look into easing.  Using an easing function you can animate the rotation so that it slows down over time smoothly.  In Greensock, it's as simple as writing something like

Tween.to(elementToAnimate, 2seconds, {rotate: 360, easing: Cubic.easeOut})

I'm not a Swift developer but this guy has created a library of easing functions that might give you the same functionality:

https://github.com/craiggrummitt/SpriteKitEasingSwift